# How to manipulate the headers of a multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
dic = {'US':{'Traffic':{'new':1415, 'repeat':670}, 'Sales':{'new':67068, 'repeat':105677}},
      'UK': {'Traffic':{'new':230, 'repeat':156}, 'Sales':{'new':4568, 'repeat':10738}}}
d1 = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in dic.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            d1[(k, k2)].update({k1: v2})


df.insert(loc=2, column=' ', value=None)
df.insert(loc=0, column=('', 'Mode'), value='Website')

df.columns = df.columns.rename("Q3", level=0)
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Metric", level=1)
```

The dataframe looks like this:[image: current dataframe]

How do I change the headers to look like this: [image: required output]

I was trying this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Skateboard", level=0)
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Q3", level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Metric", level=2)
```

But I get an IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 2 levels, not 3

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @thing10, I've edited what I tried in the post